# Why does the power supply into the op amp change from DC to AC?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, simulation, ltspice

[image]

This is an AC power supply made from transformers, and is rectified into a positive DC supply and negative DC supply.
Without the op-amp the supply generates ~15V and ~-15V.
However, when the op amp is added, the power supply starts generating AC rather than DC.

What is the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: In addition to Spehro's answer below, you have a sine generator on the op-amp non-inverting input. Wouldn't that help explain it?

Comment: Also check the values for your transformer. At 50Hz, those values will explode. The primary should be on the orders of Henry, maybe even tens or more for your given case. You may need to increase the simulation time, too, to allow settling transients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need significantly more capacitance from each rail to ground. Try 470uF or something like that in parallel with C3 and in parallel with C5.

But if you're using a fancy high performance amplifier like that one, you're probably going to want to regulate the supply rails in reality. So that would mean a positive and a negative regulator, in addition to the aforementioned electrolytic caps and whatever additional parts the regulators require.

An approximate formula for the p-p ripple on an unregulated supply is:

Vp-p = \$\frac{t_{hcyc} C}{I_{SUPPLY}}\$ where Isupply is the current drawn from the supply, C is the filter capacitance in farads and thcyc is the half-cycle time of the mains (0.01 seconds in the case of a 50Hz mains supply).

When you add regulators, provided the valleys of your ripple stays well above the dropout voltage of the regulators, your ripple will be greatly attenuated by the regulator, perhaps down to tens of microvolts for a good regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors are too small to hold enough charge between AC peaks. Increase capacitors to 100 uF for testing. And C3 polarity is wrong.

Comment: At 0.1 uF, C3 and C5 are probably not polarized, but yes, if C3 is polarized it is the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing a high ripple voltage onthe supply rails.

You need bulk storage capacitors of 100 uF or more from each supply rail to Ground.

The existing capacitors do not store enough charge to keep the voltage somewhat stable betwwen the AC voltage peaks.